# Не получается отрисовать картинку в JAVA

Tags: java, graphics

Не получается отрисовать картинку

```
package mainpacekage;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Main {
    static Image Load_bg;
    static Image bg;

    public static  void loadImage() {
        Load_bg = new ImageIcon("Graphics/Load_bg.jpg").getImage();
    }

    public static  void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(Load_bg, 0, 0, 1280, 720, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadImage();
        paintComponent();
        Windows.CreateGUI(1280, 720);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Спроси, если что-то не ясно

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private Image Load_bg;
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Main(){
        add(panel);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        try {
            Load_bg = ImageIO.read(new File("undefined.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g2.drawImage(Load_bg, 0, 0, 200, 200, null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setSize(200,200);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

//200 и 200 это размеры моей картинки. Меняй под себя

Comment: не получается вызвать метод **paintComponent**

Comment: какая именно ошибка ? скрин